# ASMX webservice to ORACLE DB times out on the first connection

Tags: c#, web-services, oracle, asmx, odp.net

I have written a C# app that communicates with a (ASMX) webservice deployed on another machine. The webservice connects to and performs operations on a backend database located on a third tier.

All DB operations in the app are called from a static class called `DataLayerFunctor`. Here is a snippet of the class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using WebserviceTest.DataLayer;
using WebserviceTest.SecurityLayer;
using SettingsAlias = WebserviceTest.Properties;

namespace WebserviceTest
{
    public static class DataLayerFunctor
    {
        public static MyWebserviceReference.Service1 myWebService;
        private static string HOST = "192.168.1.100";
        private static string PORT = "1521";
        private static string DATABASE = "orcl";
        private static string USERNAME = "MY_USER";
        private static string PASSWORD = "123";
        private static string ORACLE_CONNECTION_STRING = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST={0})(PORT={1})))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME={2})));Users Id={3};Password={4};";
        public static List<UserGroup> UserGroupsList { get; set; }
        public static List<Role> RolesList { get; set; }

        public static Dictionary<UserGroup,Role> GroupsToRoles { get; set; }

        static DataLayerFunctor()
        {
            HOST = CryptoServices.DecryptText(SettingsAlias.Settings.Default.HOST,CryptoServices.DEFAULT_KEY) ?? HOST;
            PORT = CryptoServices.DecryptText(SettingsAlias.Settings.Default.PORT,CryptoServices.DEFAULT_KEY )?? PORT;
            DATABASE = CryptoServices.DecryptText(SettingsAlias.Settings.Default.DATABASE,CryptoServices.DEFAULT_KEY) ?? DATABASE;
            USERNAME = CryptoServices.DecryptText(SettingsAlias.Settings.Default.USER_NAME,CryptoServices.DEFAULT_KEY) ?? USERNAME;
            PASSWORD = CryptoServices.DecryptText(SettingsAlias.Settings.Default.PASSWORD,CryptoServices.DEFAULT_KEY) ?? PASSWORD;
            ORACLE_CONNECTION_STRING = SettingsAlias.Settings.Default.ORACLE_CONNECTION_STRING ?? ORACLE_CONNECTION_STRING;

            HOST = "192.168.1.6";
            PORT = "1521";
            DATABASE = "orcl";
            USERNAME = "ALAMAL_BANK";
            PASSWORD = "123";


            myWebService = new MyWebserviceReference.Service1();

            myWebService.Url = "http://192.168.1.6/MyWebservice/Service1.asmx";
            //myWebService.Url = CryptoServices.DecryptText(SettingsAlias.Settings.Default.WebserviceURL,CryptoServices.DEFAULT_KEY);
            myWebService.Timeout = 36000;            

            //Load enumeration tables
            LoadGroupsToRoles();
        }

        public static void LoadGroupsToRoles() {
            string query = "SELECT * FROM GROUPS_TO_ROLES";
            DataTable groupsToRoles = myWebService.GetTableParamOracle(query, HOST, PORT, DATABASE, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
            GroupsToRoles = new Dictionary<UserGroup, Role>();
            foreach (DataRow groupsToRolesRow in groupsToRoles.Rows)
            {
                Role role = RolesList.First((i) => i.RoleId == groupsToRolesRow["ROLE_ID_FK"] as long?);
                UserGroup userGroup = UserGroupsList.First((i) => i.GroupId == groupsToRolesRow["GROUP_ID_FK"] as long?);
                GroupsToRoles.Add(userGroup, role);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the first connection to the database always fails. So, I need to rerun the app to get a connection which is unacceptable when the application is deployed. The other thing is that the connection gets reset after few minutes. How can I keep the connection alive?

I am using:
ORACLE 11g DB
ODP.NET
C# 4
SOAP Webservice

Webservice code:

```
public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

logger.LogCreator _log = new logger.LogCreator(@"C:\GDW_logs");
public static long DataTableCounter = 1;
string oracleConnection = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST={0})(PORT={1})))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME={2})));User Id={3};Password={4};";                

    [WebMethod]
    public DataTable GetTableParamOracle(string sqltext, string host, string port, string database, string username, string password)
    {
        OracleConnection SQLConnection = new OracleConnection(string.Format(oracleConnection, host, port, database, username, password));

        OracleDataAdapter dad = new OracleDataAdapter(sqltext, SQLConnection);
        DataTable dtb = new DataTable("DataTable" + (DataTableCounter++));
        SQLConnection.Open();

        try
        {

            dad.Fill(dtb);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _log.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            SQLConnection.Close();
        }


        return dtb;
    }
}
```

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: Can you post the code from the service? The client side code doesn't tell us what you're doing with Oracle.

Comment: @Tridus I have added a snippet from the webservice for the method used. Namely, GetTableParamOracle.

Comment: @John Saunders, I agree but I have been given the project as it is. My superiors still cling to the old technologies. Thanks.

Comment: 1) the connection and dataadapter should be in `using` blocks. 2) Don't just log `ex.Message` if you want to know what happened. Log `ex.ToString()`. 3) How does the caller even know there was an exception? What if the `DataTable` is partially filled, then an exception is thrown? You'll return the partial `DataTable`. You might do better to add `throw;` after the log call, and the caller will at least receive an exception.

Comment: If some error happens for any reason, it will be logged even if the method returned an incomplete datatable. That said, your suggestion to a throw statement after the logging is reasonable. I tend to think that the problem is related to Oracel 11g particularly since we have similar methods in the web service that works on SQL Server and it works fine. But the Oracle connection does not work from the first time only the second. Might be something related to the listener.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is this is a provider issue, particularly name resolution.  Make sure the "host" param of your GetTableParamOracle method is fully qualified.  Ie, "myoracleinstance.mydomain.org" and not just "myoracleinstance".

You could isolate the issue by making sure an alias exists for this instance in tnsnames.ora and using tnsping to test.  The first ping will come back slower than the rest.

If that doesn't seem to be the issue than you may want to trace the provider and see if you can identify the portion of the call that is hanging up:

```
  <oracle.dataaccess.client>
    <settings>
      <add name="TraceFileName" value="c:\temp\odpnet1.trc"/>
      <add name="TraceLevel" value="63"/>
    </settings>
  </oracle.dataaccess.client>
```

Regarding "connection is reset", it would help to know which error you're getting.  It could be a DBA job that's terminating old connections which should be turned off or maximized for a service account.  You can/should set min pool size=0, which will eventually allow all connections to be terminated.  If you have very 'spikey' traffic, you may not have much choice to either set Validate Connection = true, disable pooling, or handle errors from opening stale connections manually.  See the [odp.net documentation on connection pooling](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E10927_01/featConnecting.htm#i1006393) for more info.

Comment: Is your host name fully qualified?  I believe the default OracleConnection.ConnectionTimeout is 15 seconds and the last time I had this issue the initial dns resolution took 17 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

> The other thing is that the connection gets reset after few minutes.
>   How can I keep the connection alive?

If you're talking about the connection between the client and the web server, you don't. ASMX SOAP services don't work that way. It creates a connection, makes requests, and closes it. You can keep the same service object around for a while, but it's always making new connections even if you do. (Because of that I tend to discard the service objects fairly frequently and just have a method to get a new one when I need it.)

If you're talking about the database connection... well your code isn't trying to hold a connection open. It's creating a connection in the context of a method call. It's going to create it, use it, then let it go away when the method ends. You could hold some connections open by enabling connection pooling ([see the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/html/B28089_01/OracleConnectionClass.htm)), and that way when your code tries to make the connection the database will have one open already to speed it up.

Note that some of the comments are entirely correct. Your connection should be created inside a using statement:

```
using (OracleConnection SQLConnection = new OracleConnection(string.Format(oracleConnection, host, port, database, username, password))) {
// do stuff
}
```

That will ensure it's properly disposed, and makes the connection available again to the connection pool for the next time you need it. In your application code you'll be opening/closing connections, but in fact they will be kept open between the server and the database automatically (ODP.net handles it).

> The problem is that the first connection to the database always fails.
>   So, I need to rerun the app to get a connection which is unacceptable
>   when the application is deployed.

What error is the database giving when it fails? Is it just a timeout on the service, or is there a database error? If it's just a timeout, ODP.net has been known to take a while to load the first time in some cases. Another possibility is that since you're having the client send the connection information, it could be sending something wrong on the first request.

Comment: It timed out. It takes a while to and then connection fails. I run it again and it succeeds. As long as I am making consecutive operation it will work fine but as soon as I stop it will timeout again. If I run the program and made operations on the DB in a consecutive manner it works fine. But if I waited for some time before making another operation it will timeout.

Comment: That sounds like the issue I've seen some people have where it just takes a very long time to initially load ODP.net for some reason. I'm honestly sure how how to resolve that, as it never takes that long for me.